# SELECT that is null if there is one more register in this date that is not null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query that I can't produce...

This is my table capturainfo

```
captureid   int(11)
userid      int(11) 
date        date
dateinit    datetime
datefin     datetime
```

I need to select all rows that have `datefin=null` and is not the last row of the day ( ie there is one more row with date is the same day but `dateinit1<dateinit2`.

I just can't do it.

Here are some attempts I've made:

The basic one:

```
SELECT * FROM capturainfo where date < "2015-02-27" 
AND datefin is null
```

it gets me all datefin is null, but I can't know if there is one more row in the same day.

```
SELECT * FROM capturainfo a where date < "2015-02-27" 
AND datefin is null 
AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM capturainfo b WHERE a.datefin<= b.datefin) AND a.userid = b.userid )
```

... Well this last one doesn't work.

here is the data sample

```
+-----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     id    | userid |    date    |      dateinit       |     datefin         |
+-----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    0001   | 2034   | 2015-02-20 | 2015-02-20 11:41:31 | 2015-02-20 20:16:07 |
|    0002   | 1789   | 2015-02-20 | 2015-02-20 12:41:31 | 2015-02-20 13:43:34 |
|    0003   | 1432   | 2015-02-20 | 2015-02-20 12:55:33 |         NULL        |
|    0004   | 1432   | 2015-02-20 | 2015-02-20 13:44:21 | 2015-02-20 13:45:31 |
|    0005   | 1444   | 2015-02-20 | 2015-02-20 14:41:31 |         NULL        |
+-----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

In this case, query should return id 0003 because user 1432 have made a posterior register in the same day

Anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: You should describe your query more specifically (what is the last row of the day- does it depend on date, dateinit, datefin?), maybe adding the minimum amount of example data and expected results. But your query seems to be similar to a common query pattern called "groupwise maximum": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Tx for your comment, I will update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had one closing parentheses too many in the latter query. You also have columns `date` and `datefin` and the distinction between the two is not clear. If you want to do a comparison per day, you have to make sure both rows are from the same day in the inner query (`a.date = b.date`) and there has to exist b.dateinit where `a.dateinit` is smaller (`<`) not smaller or equal (`<=`). You also erroneously compare `datefin` columns in the subquery when you should compare `dateinit` columns. It seems you want to get rows from dates older than `2015-02-27`:

```
SELECT * FROM capturainfo a where date < "2015-02-27" 
AND datefin is null 
AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM capturainfo b WHERE a.date = b.date AND a.dateinit < b.dateinit AND a.userid = b.userid )
```

Comment: I use navicat in mac, and it take ::date like a syntax error. So I delete it, and query doesn't return anything, 0 rows :( date is yyyy-mm-dd and datefin include hours. date may be considerated like redundant but it make the query easier

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Made the answer in postgresql syntax by mistake. Corrected in the answer.

Comment: Tx ! But still no record returned!

Comment: Added another correction to the answer: you compared datefin in the subquery when it should have been dateinit.

Comment: it seems to works properly ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
select * from capturainfo where date <= 'your last date' AND datefin='null'
```

hope it will help.